# Problema con la ejecucion del programa

Tags: c

Lo que quiero hacer, es que el usuario ingrese un texto, luego en la funcion `formaTabla` que compare la cadena ingresada con las que haya guardadas en la tabla y si la cadena no se encuentra repetida que la guarde en la tabla.

El problema que tengo es que cuando lo ejecuto, ejecuta todo hasta que muestra la cadena ingresada luego no funciona mas. Quisiera saber si es que tengo algun error que efectivamente yo no lo estoy encontrando.

Y quisiera saber como es la sintaxis para reservar memoria para un arreglo de estructuras, ya que lo intente pero me marca error

```
struct tab
{ char cadena[25];
int alfa; };


char * ingresaCadena ();
struct tab* formaTabla (char *, int *filas);

int main()
{
char *texto,rta='s';
int filas=0,op;
struct tab *puntabla;

printf("Ingrese una de las siguientes opciones:  \n");
printf(" 1-Ingresar texto y formar tabla \n 2-Buscar \n 3-Salir \n");
scanf("%d",&op);
while(getchar()!='\n');
while (op>0 && op<4)
     { switch (op)
             {  case 1:  while(rta=='s')
                           { texto=ingresaCadena();
                             printf("El texto ingresado es:   %s  \n",   texto);
                             puntabla=formaTabla(texto,&filas);
                             printf ("Desea ingresar otro texto? S o N \n");
                             scanf("%c",&op); }
                        for (int i=0; i<filas;i++)
                                { printf("Las cadenas ingresadas son: \n");
                                   printf("%s \n", *puntabla->cadena); } } }













system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

char * ingresaCadena ()
{
 char *t=(char*)calloc(25,sizeof(char));
 printf("Ingrese el texto \n");
 gets(t);
 return t; }

 struct tab* formaTabla (char *tex, int *f)
 {
 struct tab tabla[100];
 int var,longi;
 for (int i=0;i<=*f;i++)
 {var=strcmp(tabla[i].cadena,tex);
    if (var!=0)
      { strcpy(tabla[*f].cadena,tex);
        longi=strlen(tabla[*f].cadena);
        tabla[*f].alfa=longi;
        *f++; } }
  return (&tabla[*f-1]) ; }
```

Comment: Con punteros estas usando memoria dinámica, si queres reservar memoria para arreglo de struct 

struct
{
int a;
}nombreEstructura[tamañoArreglo];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si un programa se queda congelado se debe normalmente un bloqueo producido por un bucle.

En tu programa únicamente tienes dos bucles, luego el problema debe encontrar ahí... efectivamente:

```
  while(rta=='s')
  { texto=ingresaCadena();
    printf("El texto ingresado es:   %s  \n",   texto);
    puntabla=formaTabla(texto,&filas);
    printf ("Desea ingresar otro texto? S o N \n");
    scanf("%c",&op);
  }
```

El bucle verifica el valor de `rta`... pero esa variable no se modifica dentro del bucle, luego no habrá forma de salir del mismo... es un problema asociado a la técnica de *copypaste*.

La solución es simple... sustituir `&op` por `&rta`.

Eso sí, considera sacar los dos bulces del `case`.

---

**EDITO**

Aunque no lo estés reportando, ya que aún no has llegado, tienes otros problemas en el código:

```
struct tab* formaTabla (char *tex, int *f)
{
  struct tab tabla[100];
  // ...
  return (&tabla[*f-1]);
}
```

Dado que `tabla` no es una variable estática, el puntero que devuelves no va a ser válido y te dará problemas. No tiene demasiado sentido que la tabla sea interna de la función... el sentido común me dice que esa estructura tendría más sentido que estuviese declarada fuera de la función:

```
int main()
{
  struct tab tabla[100];
  // ...
  while (op>0 && op<4)
  {
    switch (op)
    {
    case 1:
      while(rta=='s')
      {
        // ...
        formaTabla(tabla, texto,&filas);
      }
    }
  }
}

void formaTabla(sturct tab* tabla, char* tex, int* f)
{
  // struct tab tabla[100] <<--- Ya no es necesario
}
```

Otro error de tu código, aunque menos visible, es que tiene fugas de memoria.
Tu función reserva memoria dinámica:

```
char *t=(char*)calloc(25,sizeof(char));
```

¿Dónde se libera dicha memoria? En ningún sitio. Yo te sugeriría no hacer reservas de memoria en tu programa dado lo sencillo que es.. pero si las haces al menos preocúpate de liberar la memoria:

```
texto=ingresaCadena();
printf("El texto ingresado es:   %s  \n",   texto);
puntabla=formaTabla(texto,&filas);
free(texto); // <<---
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! ya me pongo a realizar los cambios!!

Comment: El problema es que la tabla la tengo que crear en la funcion. Ya que el ejercicio especificamente nos da el siguiente prototipo de funcion:

     struct tab* formaTabla (char *, int *filas);

Por ende no lo puedo modificar, entonces es la uncia forma que se me ocurrio hacer la tabla dentro de la funcion. Como puedo hacer para retornarla? @eferion

Comment: Declara la tabla como estática